# Feed for all activity on a SE2 meta, including comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, stackexchange-2.0, feed, per-site-meta

Is there a way to get a feed of all activity on a SE 2.0 meta, including new comments to any question or answer? Since the comments are used much more like a discussion forum it can be annoying to miss them, limiting the discussion only to the OP and the one commenter. The meta is created to shape the community, so it's important that the whole community can easily see what items are being discussed now. Per-site metas, certainly in the first months, usually don't have many questions so I don't see a risk of generating too much traffic.